# Reading kml file using python

Tags: python

I have been battling for days to read coordinates `LineString` using `fastkml library` in python.

I have imported geometry module in my main program. I am reading like this.

 My kml file is stored in string called `doc`

```
X = Geometry
Z=x._get,_coordinates(doc)
```

I got an error that says

> the module object has no attributes find

Comment: please share actual codes, and error messages..

Answer (score 0):

from fastkml import kml
import re
from fastkml.geometry import Geometry
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

def print_child_features(element):

```
if not getattr(element, 'features', None):
    return
for feature in element.features():
    y = feature.to_string()
    return y
```

def print_child2_features(element):
    """ Prints the name of every child node of the given element, recursively """
    if not getattr(element, 'features', None):
        return
    for feature in element.features():
        print feature.name
        print_child2_features(feature)

def get_distance(coordinates_str):
    """gets distance of one path from coordinates string in form of:
    14.81363432237944,53.57016581501523,0 14.81411766813742,53.56923005549378,0 14.81880340335202,53.56879451890311 ...
    look at:
        http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#coordinates
    """
    sum_distance = 0.0
    arr = []
    coordinates = []
    if ' ' in coordinates_str:
        arr = coordinates_str.split(' ')
    if len(arr) > 1:
        for s in arr:
            if ',' in s:
                pt = s.split(',')
                pos_latt = (float(pt[0].strip()), 0, 0)
                pos_long = (float(pt[1].strip()), 0, 0)
                position = (pos_latt, pos_long)
                coordinates.append(position)
    if coordinates:
        for i in range(len(coordinates) - 1):
            start = coordinates[i]
            stop = coordinates[i + 1]
            sum_distance += distance.points2distance(start, stop)
    return sum_distance

if **name** == '**main**':

```
#fname = input("Enter KML file name ")
fname = "DBN.kml"
k = kml.KML()
with open(fname) as kmlFile:
    k.from_string(kmlFile.read()) 
x = Geometry()

doc = print_child_features(k)
z= x._get_coordinates(doc)
print z
length=0
if length <= 10:
   print("Transciver is LR")
elif length > 10 and length <= 40:
   print("Transciver is ER")
else:
   print("Transciver is ER")
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the code you have written. But I have written code to read coordinates from Linestrings and other Geometries using fastkml library, so I can help.

```
# import necessary modules 
from fastkml import kml, geometry 

k = kml.KML() # create fastkml object
k.from_string(doc.encode('utf-8')) # read doc string
document = list(k.features())
self.parse_placemarks(document) 

# parse features throughout the KML File
def parse_placemarks(self, document):
        for feature in document:
            if isinstance(feature, kml.Placemark):  # when there is no folder
                placemark = feature
                self.parse_geometries(placemark)
        for feature in document:
            if isinstance(feature, kml.Folder):
                self.parse_placemarks(list(feature.features()))
            if isinstance(feature, kml.Document):
                self.parse_placemarks(list(feature.features()))

# parse geometry 
def parse_geometries(self, placemark):
   if hasattr(placemark, "geometry"):
      if isinstance(placemark.geometry, geometry.LineString):
         self.linestring(placemark)

# parse linestring
def linestring(self, line):
x, y = self.compute_coordinates(line.geometry)

# find coordinates
def compute_coordinates(self, geometry):
        lons = []
        lats = []
        for coordinates in geometry.coords:
            lons.append(coordinates[0])
            lats.append(coordinates[1])
        return (lons, lats)
```

You can find how to extract coordinates of other geometries and more about fastkml here : https://medium.com/@wwaryan/the-definite-only-guide-to-fastkml-58b8e19b8454

Comment: I get the error NameError: name 'self' is not defined. How is self supposed to work here? The same problem arises when following the post in Medium. Thanks